# Lambda functions C++: Does capturing the index of a loop make a difference?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

In the two lambdas inside the for-loops below, an expert (or at least someone more expert than I) recommended using the 'j' index, which is shown in the second loop. I want to understand why, when functionally, the output is no different.

My executable program is on Github [here](https://github.com/NonCreature0714/Concurrency_and_multi_threading).

```
for(int j = 0;j<recPtr->numThreads;j++){

    recPtr->heads[j] = 0;
    recPtr->tails[j] = 0;
    headsPtr = &recPtr->heads[j]; // Get the address of the index of the array, one element for each thread for heads.
    tailsPtr = &recPtr->tails[j]; // Get the address of the index of the array, one element for each thread for heads.

    threads.push_back(thread([headsPtr, tailsPtr, timesToToss]()
    {
        for(int k=0;k<timesToToss;k++)
        { 
            if (Tosser(dre)) ++(*headsPtr); 
            else ++(*tailsPtr); 
        } 
    })); //Toss a coin!
}


for (int j = 0; j < recPtr->numThreads; j++)
{

    recPtr->heads[j] = 0;
    recPtr->tails[j] = 0;
    headsPtr = &recPtr->heads[j]; // Get the address of the index of the array, one element for each thread for heads.
    tailsPtr = &recPtr->tails[j]; // Get the address of the index of the array, one element for each thread for heads.

    threads.push_back(thread([j, headsPtr, tailsPtr, timesToToss]()
    {
        for(int k=0;k<timesToToss;k++)
        {   
            if (Tosser(dre)) ++(*headsPtr);
            else ++(*tailsPtr);
        }
    })); //Toss a coin!
}
```

Comment: Beware of people who call themselves "experts" when it comes to C++...

Comment: ...or any other language too. Calling someone else an expert, fine. Calling themselves, no. But I'm not sure I understand what you want. How do you want to use j?

Comment: Understood you there - from my perspective he/she solved what seemed like a difficult multithreading problem I spent over a week working on, so maybe "more expert than I" is more accurate. I'm the one calling them an expert.

Comment: @deviantfan my question is exactly yours - why 'j'?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 So the `thread([j` is all there is of j? Because then you're right, it's useless. It makes it possible to use `j` inside of the lambda, but you're not using it at all.

Comment: @deviantfan I think the purpose of 'j' was to make sure the threads weren't colliding, because I was also re-pointing pointers with every iteration, and passing the re-pointed address of the pointers to lambda in the thread.

Comment: @deviantfan ah, ok, thanks

Comment: I'm the so-called expert, and my apologies. I have no clue how the `j` got in there. Legacy of my screwing with something in the lambda at some point that hung around is my best guess.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda does not use `j`, hence there is no reason to capture it. It provides you with no benefit.

But you're making your closure bigger by an `int`, incurring extra `int` copies and additionally confusing future viewers of your code (including yourself), who might wonder if a previous iteration of the code had needed the `j` before.

So don't capture `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the variable `j` by value in your lambda is redundant as you're not using it in the lambda body...

But on the other hand, if `j` was being used in the lambda body then yes, it needs to be captured to be used. More about lambda capture [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Here is a small example:

```
int main()
{
    int j { 9 };
    auto lambda = [ ]() { cout << j << '\n'; };
               //  ^  error 'j' not captured

    lambda();
}
```